# Unable to read excel file from S3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue

i have this small piece of code which is working in local system

```py
import pandas as pd
import glob
import openpyxl

# path of folder
path=r'C:\Users\Preet\Desktop\python_files'

#Display list of files
filenames=glob.glob(path+"\*.xlsx")
print(filenames)

#initializing data frame
finalexcelsheet=pd.DataFrame()

#to iteriate excel
for file in filenames:
    df = pd.concat(pd.read_excel(file,sheet_name=None), ignore_index=True,sort=False)

    #print(df)
    finalexcelsheet=finalexcelsheet.append(df,ignore_index=True)
print(finalexcelsheet)
finalexcelsheet.to_excel('C:\\Users\\preet\\Desktop\\python_files\\final.xlsx',index=False).
```

However when i try to read the same xlsx files from s3 bucket it just creates a empty data frame and stops and says job succeeded.below is the code for s3..Please let me know if anything i m missing in code below

```py
import boto3
import pandas as pd
import glob
import openpyxl

# path of folder

bucketname = "sit-bucket-lake-raw-static-5464"
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
my_bucket = s3.Bucket(bucketname)
source = "sit-bucket-lake-raw-static-5464/Staging/"
target = "sit-bucket-lake-raw-static-5464/branch/2020/12/"

#Display list of files
filenames=glob.glob(source+"\*.xlsx")
print(filenames)

#initializing data frame
finalexcelsheet=pd.DataFrame()

#to iteriate excel
for file in filenames:
    df = pd.concat(pd.read_excel(file,sheet_name=None), ignore_index=True,sort=False)

finalexcelsheet=finalexcelsheet.append(df,ignore_index=True)
print(finalexcelsheet)
finalexcelsheet.to_excel('target\final.xlsx',index=False)
```

Comment: You don't seem to be using `my_bucket` anywhere in the code. The normal process would be to **download the file** to local disk, then process it like you normally do.

Comment: In your glob statement you can build your file reference like this https://my-bucket.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/puppy.png using the correct bucket, region and file names. You can't read a file directly how you are building the filenames. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/VirtualHosting.html#virtual-hosted-style-access